# Does Starfleet have rules banning racial prejudice?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Gene Roddenberry famously defined the Star Trek universe as one in which humans have moved past division and prejudice. Nonetheless key characters are seen to exhibit prejudicial behaviour towards other characters based on racial characteristics.

- McCoy describes Vulcans as “damned annoying at times”. Not the one guy (the half-Vulcan Spock) he interacted with a lot, but Vulcans.
- Kirk calls Kruge a “Klingon bastard”. Albeit at an emotionally distraught time, it’s nonetheless unfortunate that he chooses that particular adjective (as he finds to his cost later). He could have said “bastard who looks a lot like Emmet L. Brown”, “murderous bastard” or something.
- Worf is basically a one-man vendetta against the Ferengi. He doesn’t think the Academy is unwise to admit Nog, he thinks they’re unwise to admit a Ferengi, for example.

None of these examples led to a reprimand or disciplinary action *from Starfleet*. Do the higher ups at San Francisco think of this as “harmless banter”, or is there in-universe evidence that Starfleet has rules against racism and enforces them?

Comment: This is a really interesting question that I hope gets an answer. I'm not sure if Star Trek was meant to be a "post racial" society or what. In the real world we're more sensitive and keen on passing policies to reduce oppression and prejudice, yet in Star Trek they act like they're beyond that sort of thing. I remember when Uhura was accidentally called a "negress" and Uhura asked why she should take offense. She said, "we've learned not to fear words." Episodes like "Measure of a Man" support the idea there are laws based around protecting minorities, though.

Comment: There is a difference between judging someone based on their race and judging them based on their culture.  I would argue that in each of the cases mentioned the Federation member was reacting to cultural characteristics rather than racial ones.